# Multivariable proof of $lim_{(x,y)\to(a,b)} \frac{sin(f(x,y))}{f(x,y)}=1$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, trigonometry, proof-writing, proof-explanation, epsilon-delta

I know the typical result when it's the limit in one variable, but I can't find a multivariable epsilon-delta proof to the following problem:

> Let $f:B_r(a,b) \rightarrow \Bbb R$ such that $f$ is defined over $B_r(a,b)-\{(a,b)\}$ and $lim_{(x,y)\to(a,b)} f(x,y) = 0$. Prove that
>   $$lim_{(x,y)\to(a,b)} \frac{sin(f(x,y))}{f(x,y)}=1$$

$B_r(a,b)$ is the ball with radius $r$ and center $(a,b)$

I basically don't know how to take the known limit to an extra dimension. Where should I start? Also if you know of a book where I can find the proof or another website where it's explained it'll be helpful. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Why don't you write down how you would prove it if we were in one dimension? Then write $\mathbb x=(x,y)$ and see what, if anything, is different about this case.

Comment: @Jason can I just change the $x$ in $\frac{sinx}{x}$ for $f(x,y)$ ? Just like that?

Comment: I think it would be a good idea for you prove that, if $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=0$, then $\lim_{x\to a}\frac{\sin(f(x))}{f(x)}=1$. Can you do that?

Answer (score 1):

Let $\epsilon>0$ we know that  $\lim_{z \longrightarrow 0}\frac{sin(z)}{z}=1$ thus $\exists \delta_1$ such that $|z|< \delta_1 \Longrightarrow |\frac{sin(z)}{z}-1|< \epsilon$

But $\lim_{x \longrightarrow (a,b)}f(x,y)=0$  and $\delta_1>0$ thus for $\delta_1>0$, $\exists \delta>0$ such that $||x-(a,b)||< \delta \Longrightarrow |f(x,y)|<\delta_1$

If we set $z=f(x,y)$,
then we found $\delta>0$ such that $||x-(a,b)||< \delta \Longrightarrow |f(x,y)| <\delta_1 \Longrightarrow |\frac{\sin{f(x,y)}}{f(x,y)}-1|<\epsilon$